# Windows 7 - disable GPO for all the users including the users who will have the Administrator rights except only for built in administrator account,

Tags: windows-7, administrator, group-policy

I need to prevent the Windows 7 desktop users **(who will have the Administrator rights in Windows 7 desktop machine)** from editing or accessing the Group policy.
The built in Administrator should only able to open and edit the Group policy.

**My requirement here is:** I have done some GPO changes through the local built in Administrator user in a windows 7 desktop machine which is connected to my local domain,
But, few domain users added to that Windows 7 desktop machine in local administrator group so that they can able login with their account to that machine to work and run the applications.

but, I don't want those added domain users to change or edit the GPO settings which I did some changes as the Local Administrator in that machine.

So is it possible to do that ?

Comment: You will be unable to prevent a user in the network Administrator user group from modifying the group policy.  The built-in user group would not have the correct AD permissions

Comment: So I cannot able to prevent Domain users who are all added into the windows 7 local administrator group.
My requirement here is: I have done some gpo changes in a domain connected windows 7 desktop machine from local buil in Administrator account,
But, few domain users added to that machine as local administrator. I don't want them to change or edit the GPO settings.
So is it possible to do that ?

Comment: You indicated these users were in the Administrator group.  I assumed by that statement you mean the domain Administrator group.  A domain user is in the local Administrator group can indeed be prevented from launching the group policy editor unless they have access to the DC.  What have you attempted exactly?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ramhound and I have updated my question :)

Comment: Any help on this ?